# Enable Debugging of Web App in VS2012 in non-IE Browsers

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

In an inherited Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 WebApplication targeted at .net 4.5, I have a JavaScript function with multiple breakpoints that are not being recognized.

I am running under Windows 7 Home Premium in an Admin account and using IIS Express.

My Web.config reports that I have debugging enabled in the projects Web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

When running, the "JavaScript Console" and "DOM Explorer" items in the DEBUG->WINDOWS menu are grayed out.

The project builds without errors or warnings.

The project properties report that the Configuration is "Active (Debug)" and the Platform is "Active(Any CPU)".

The breakpoint detection/operation fails for me in Chrome, Firefox, Pale Moon, and VS's "Page Inspector", but works in Internet Explorer.

On the Advanced tab of Internet Options dialog, "Script Debugging" is not disabled for either Internet Explorer or Other.

Based on other's suggestions, I have emptied by bin directory, restarted VS, and even rebooted the computer.

How do I get Visual Studio to debug with browsers other than IE?

Comment: do you have a server breakpoint as well going on? from what I understand in 2012 you should have two instances open for debugging client and server and if the server side is in a breakpoint the client side will be disabled. See here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/28/javascript-native-interop-debugging-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Comment: Mike:  I'm not sure that link applies.  It seems to deal with JS & native with 2 different debuggers.  I'm strictly JS and the debugging works in IE but not in any other browsers.